# CSV file output is in Doctype HTML format

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365, clientcontext

I am using the below code to read the csv file from SharePoint. But in ouput i am getting DOCTYPE HTML format output.

Can anyone help me on this:-
'''

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests


url = "https://sharepoint/AllItems.aspx"
fileurl = "/Shared Documents/folder/test.csv"
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user("Username", "Password")   
ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print('Authentication Successful')
response = File.open_binary(ctx, "Shared%20Documents%2FHCFM&FolderCTID=0x0120007B89818A32984B458F18252DBE2A2D40")
print(response.content)
```

'''
i have "Authentication Successful" but in output getting DOCTYPE HTML format.

Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We cant reproduce it for fix cause we havent token, let us reproduce it or as least give us more info about error, as output log, we will try help u

Comment: @Akshi did you ever find the solution to this?